# How to use org-drill to memorize org-drill?

Tags: org-mode, org-drill

Say I want to memorize the cloze deletion syntax of org-drill by this topic,

[image]

The problem here is when the answer is revealed the text is only displayed partially like it's been interpreted as a cloze deletion.

[image]

Any tricks or suggestions on this kind of "meta" stuff ?

Answer (score 2):

As I learn more about Org mode, I'm able to answer this question myself.

Org provides Latex-like syntax for special symbols.  To make the example in question works, we could write the answer as

```
[answer\vert\vert{}optional hint]
```

or

```
[answer\vbar\vbar{}optional hint]
```

Curly braces are used to terminate a symbol.  Before drill sessions, `(org-toggle-pretty-entities)` or `C-c C-x \` to render these notations into UTF-8 characters.